# Property [DB] does not exist on the Eloquent builder instance

Tags: laravel, eloquent

Intente con esto;

```
public function update(Request $request,$id)
{    
  DB::table('Productos')->decrement('cantidad',$request->input('nuevaCantidad'));

  return redirect('retirar_producto');
}
```

pero esto afecta toda mi columna cantidad, entonces intente esto;

```
 public function update(Request $request,$id)
{


   Productos::where('id','=',$id)
   ->DB::table('Productos')->decrement('cantidad',$request->input('nuevaCantidad'));

    return redirect('retirar_producto');
}
```

pero esto me da el siguiente error;

> Property [DB] does not exist on the Eloquent builder instance.

Comment: Es simple, simplemente debes quitar ese DB::table() en tu segunda consulta, ya que al hacer `Productos::` ya estás teniendo una referencia a la tabla, lo que haces es repetirlo dos veces de distinta forma.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No es buena idea combinar `Modelos` con `Query Builder (DB)`,

lo correcto seria obtener la tabla, despues el objeto, finalmente modificar

**Query Builder (DB)**

```
public function update(Request $request,$id) {
    DB::table('Productos')
       ->where('id', $id)
       ->update([
           'cantidad' => DB::raw('cantidad - '.$request->input('nuevaCantidad')),
       ]);
    return redirect('retirar_producto');
}
```

**Modelos**

```
 public function update(Request $request,$id) {
    $p = Productos::find($id);
    $p->cantidad = $p->cantidad - $request->input('nuevaCantidad');
    $p->save();
    return redirect('retirar_producto');
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Unos comentarios:

- Tu primer *query* es correcta, pero carece de una condición que determine donde se aplicará dicho decremento y por lo tanto se hace de manera general.

Alcanzaría con dejarla así:

```
DB::table('Productos')->whereId($id)
    ->decrement('cantidad',$request->input('nuevaCantidad'));
```

La segunda de forma genérica es correcta, salvo este detalle:

- Usas de forma mezclada a *DB* junto con el modelo lo cual te deriva en el error mostrado, alcanza con dejar así la consulta:

  ```
  Productos::whereId($id)->decrement('cantidad',$request->input('nuevaCantidad'));
  ```

Con respecto al error de forma mas detallada:

- El modelo `Productos` es la entidad que representa a tu tabla `productos` por lo tanto no existe necesidad de usar el *facade* para invocarla de nuevo
- El error se genera debido a que `DB` no existe en los métodos del *builder* de *Eloquent* que esta en esta ruta:

  ```
  app\vendor\laravel\framework\src\Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Builder.php
  ```

El cual te sugiero revises a detalle

**Enlaces de interés**

- [Facades en Laravel](https://laravel.com/docs/7.x/facades#facade-class-reference)
- [Método decrement](https://laravel.com/docs/7.x/queries#increment-and-decrement)
- [Eloquent builder](https://github.com/laravel/framework/blob/7.x/src/Illuminate/Database/Eloquent/Builder.php)

Answer (score 0):

Un consejo, crea los casos de uso por separado de tus controladores.

Creemos una clase `CasosUsoProductos` y dentro del él el caso de uso `setStock` con los parametros `$id` del producto y `$cantidad`

```
class CasoUsoProductos{
    public static setStock($id,$cantidad){
        $producto=Productos::find($id);//conseguimos el producto a editar
        //validamos la existencia de valor
        if($cantidad <= 0 && $producto->cantidad < ($cantidad*-1)){
            throw new Exception('Cantidad no existente');
        }
        $producto->cantidad=$producto->cantidad+$cantidad;
        $producto->save();
        return $producto;
    }
    public function agregarACarrito($id,$id_carrito,$cantidad){
        ...
    }
}
```

Llamamos a nuestra función de la siguiente manera:

```
public function update(Request $request,$id){
    $producto=CasoUsoProductos::setStock($id,$request->cantidad);
    return redirect('retirar_producto');
}
```

No olvides importar el namespace de `CasoUsoProductos`.

Dicha funcion funcionaria mas o menos asi:

```
Producto_ID=1, stock de 8: CasoUsoProductos::setStock(1,2); -> stock resultante 10
Producto_ID=4, stock de 10: CasoUsoProductos::setStock(4,-3); -> stock resultante 7
Producto_ID=5, stock de 3: CasoUsoProductos::setStock(5,-7); -> error:Cantidad no existente
Producto_ID=7, stock de 4: CasoUsoProductos::setStock(7,0); -> error:Cantidad no existente
```

En todo caso si no quieres ordenar tu codigo y deseas mantener tu formato solo edita la funcion `update`;

```
public function update(Request $request,$id){
     $cantidad=$request->cantidad; //vefirica que el numero sea negativo o solo lograras agregar y no restar
    $producto=Productos::find($id);
    if($cantidad <= 0 && $producto->cantidad < ($cantidad*-1)){
        throw new Exception('Cantidad no existente');
    }
    $producto->cantidad=$producto->cantidad+$cantidad;
    $producto->save();
    return redirect('retirar_producto');
}
```